# Need add firewall rule

Tags: centos, firewall

I have CentOS 7.3.1611 installed and there I have Icewarp mail-server installed.

When the firewall is stopped, I can connect in my web browser to the admin console, but if it is started then I can't connect to this web console. I probably have to add a rule for this address: http://random.random.net (or https). Maybe is just needed enable ports 80 and 443 which are for http/s?

How to solve this issue or state how add this firewall rule?

Comment: what are you connecting to on which protocol on which port ? what is your current firewall ? what is its current configuration, it's impossible to help without a bit of background here.

Answer (score 1):

[stackoverflow.com: Open firewall port on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729024/open-firewall-port-on-centos-7)

For you, most likely:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp --permanent
```

Comment: Thank You. Can You ale please tell me how I can disable this rule if I will need it?

Comment: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=443/tcp --permanent`

Comment: or just don't use the --permanent option, then the next firewall restart (eg: in reboot) will remove this rule.